# Is there any Javascript function similar to PHP's JSON_DECODE function?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

I'm using jQuery AJAX to load part of my web page. And my AJAX datatype is HTML. I've heard JSON is faster and I've used it too. But JSON doesn't seem to work when the data is a little big, for example:

It works when the data is short:

```
{"name" : "John Smith" , "age" : "32" , "status" : "married" }

{"name" : "Bella Gilbert" , "age" : "26" , "status" : "single" }
```

But not when the data is a little big:

```
{"name" : "John Smith" , "age" : "32" , "status" : "married" }

{"name" : "Bella Gilbert" , "age" : "26" , "status" : "single" }

{"name" : "Joseph Morgan" , "age" : "28" , "status" : "single" }

{"name" : "Paul Wesley" , "age" : "24" , "status" : "single" }
```

Is there any way I can just fetch the data without stating dataType as JSON and then decode it using javascript, as similar to PHP's function:

> json_decode($data);

Or if not then please suggest a way to handle large JSON data using jQuery AJAX. Thanks!

Comment: Size is not the problem, your JSON is invalid, you cannot just concatenate several objects like that.

Comment: Im wondering, Why is this DV? Is this a bad practice?

Answer (score 10):

use this

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(json_data);
```

It will decode the json_data

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/

Comment: Will it decode JSON or encode it? Can you please describe a little bit or show an example? Thanks.

Answer (score 9):

use `JSON.parse()` to convert a JSON string to an object:

```
var jsontext = '{"firstname":"Jesper","surname":"Aaberg","phone":["555-0100","555-0120"]}';
var contact = JSON.parse(jsontext);
document.write(contact.surname + ", " + contact.firstname);

// Output: Aaberg, Jesper
```

jquery version: (`Parses a JSON string.`)

```
var obj = jQuery.parseJSON('{"name":"John"}');
alert(obj.name);
```

Answer (score 5):

You could use the [`$.parseJSON()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) method to parse a JSON encoded string into the corresponding javascript object. But if you are performing an AJAX request to your server and the data is coming from it you don't need to use this method at all because jQuery will automatically parse the result passed to the success function:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/somescript.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {
        // result is already a parsed javascript object that you could manipulate directly here
    }
});
```

And if you write your server side script properly so that it sets the response `Content-Type` HTTP header to `application/json` (which you should always be doing anyways) you don't even need to indicate to jQuery the `dataType` parameter. jQuery will analyze this response header and automatically parse the result for you:

```
$.ajax({
    url: '/somescript.php',
    success: function(result) {
        // result is already a parsed javascript object that you could manipulate directly here
    }
});
```

Comment: But as I said, $.ajax({dataType: 'json'}) doesn't fetch back large JSON data.

Comment: What do you mean by large JSON data? Could you show an example? There is nothing that would prevent the `$.ajax` method to fetch large data. But be careful, the data must be valid JSON, otherwise jQuery will throw an error that it cannot parse it. Is your server sending valid JSON? For example what you have shown in your question is invalid JSON. You cannot just concatenate segments like that. If you want to send an array of objects you should use `[` and `]`: `[{"name" : "John Smith" , "age" : "32" , "status" : "married" },{"name" : "Bella Gilbert" , "age" : "26" , "status" : "single" }]`.

Comment: I'm using this on the server side:

[

<?php echo json_encode($data); ?>

]

Should I do it manually?

Comment: it's fine if you do it **once**. But if that's the case, you are not showing the real response in your question.

Answer (score 0):

the [jQuery.parseJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/) method can do this.

Answer (score 0):

Your json object is malformed. Should look like this:

```
[{"name" : "John Smith" , "age" : "32" , "status" : "married" },

{"name" : "Bella Gilbert" , "age" : "26" , "status" : "single" },

{"name" : "Joseph Morgan" , "age" : "28" , "status" : "single" },

{"name" : "Paul Wesley" , "age" : "24" , "status" : "single" }]
```

Use [this](http://json.parser.online.fr/) tool to check your object.